# Путь к картинке android

Tags: java, android, сервер, изображения

Хочу сделать что б нажал на кнопку "открыть картинку", открывалась галерея, выбираешь картинку. Нажимаешь на другую кнопку "отправить картинку" картинка заливалась на сервер. Хотел спросить, как сделать кнопку "открыть картинку"? Там как то через intent или что, получается нажимаем на открыть картинку, узнаем путь к картинке, потом в `File f = new File("вставляем путь")`, получается у нас есть уже путь к картинке и далее  по [этому уроку](http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106) загружаем на сервер. Или как лучше сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы открыть галерею,  надо присвоить ей следующий `onClickListener`

```
public OnClickListener btnChoosePhotoPressed = new OnClickListener() {      
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                   android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        final int ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE = 1234;
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE); 
    }
};
```

Чтобы получить выбранную картинку:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 

    switch(requestCode) { 
    case 1234:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();


            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
           // Now you have choosen image in Bitmap format in object "yourSelectedImage". You can use it in way you want! 
        }
    }

};
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016000/how-to-open-phones-gallery-through-code)

Answer (score 3):

**Старт активити выбора картинки:**

```
Button pickImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_pick);
        pickImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
            }
        });
```

**Обработка результата, можешь считать из потока imageStream данные и отправить на сервер (промежуточное сохранение в файл будет лишнем)**:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 
        switch(requestCode) { 
        case SELECT_PHOTO:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                try {
                    final Uri imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);

                    ... // обработка потока

                    // final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                    // imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```